# MVVM- How can I bind to a textbox's SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, c#-4.0

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind SelectionStart Property of Text Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175618/how-to-bind-selectionstart-property-of-text-box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following - "[How to bind SelectionStart Property of Text Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175618/how-to-bind-selectionstart-property-of-text-box)", asks a similar question and correctly indicates that **SelectionStart** cannot be bound to is it is not a dependency property (and this is true for **SelectionLength** as well).  Further down a couple of work-arounds have been provided; one using custom textbox (this would be my preference), and another using attached behaviours.