# WPF highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf

Anyone has any idea how to highlight in a textblock?

Basically i have 2 textblock and both have the same string. When I highlight part of the string in one of the textblock, the other textblock shows the same highlighted part as well. I am basically stuck at how to do the highlighting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `TextBlock` or a `TextBox`? I'm going to assume it's a `TextBox`, since `TextBlock` does not support text selection.

In that case, you can simply use data binding to keep this in sync.

```
<TextBox Name="text1" />
<TextBox Name="text2" 
       SelectionStart="{Binding Path=SelectionStart, ElementName=text1}" 
       SelectionLength="{Binding Path=SelectionLength, ElementName=text1}" />
```

This should ensure that the same area of text is selected in `text2` when the user selects it in `text1` and vice-versa.

**EDIT** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175618/how-to-bind-selectionstart-property-of-text-box) for instructions on how to bind to these properties.

If you create a custom `TextBox` as described in the linked answer, your code would look something like this:

```
<SelectionBindingTextBox Name="text1" />
<SelectionBindingTextBox Name="text2" 
       BindableSelectionStart="{Binding Path=BindableSelectionStart, ElementName=text1}" 
       BindableSelectionLength="{Binding Path=BindableSelectionLength, ElementName=text1}" />
```

Comment: Oh i tried but I have this error 


A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SelectionStart' property of type 'TextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: i use a textbox as suggested. just realised textblock cannot select text

Comment: hmm nope i still have the dependency error. I read somewhere that textbox cannot support selection dependency?

Comment: hmm i still get the same error. Is there any thing i need to set or define?

Comment: @user992618: You'll have to use your custom `TextBox` type instead of `TextBox` in order to do this.

Comment: Is there any online examples that illustrate how it is used. I am totally confused?

my xaml is as below
 <local:SelectionBindingTextBox x:Key="SelectionBindingTextBox"
                                       Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       BindableSelectionStart="{Binding SelectionStart, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       BindableSelectionLength="{Binding SelectionLength, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       />

and my textbox will just follow the example as given above?