# WPF with MVVM: How to insert the text in a textbox based on the caret position(not in code behind)

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox which is binded to a property “display” of Viewmodel class

My current logic:
I have a keyboard whenever key is pressed the key is appending at the end of existing string text box.

What I want: 
when key is pressed, based on the cursor position my key should be appended(not at the end)
EX: “Stack” is a string. My current cursor position is after “S”, if I press the key “G”, property “display” of Viewmodel class should have “SGtack” (textbox shows “SGtack” but “Display” is still StackG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ViewModel you must have :

**display**  Property to keep the text of textbox

**CurrentPosition** to bind the SelectionStart of textbox

and **newChar** which is the new character you wanna add to the textbox

when you click a button you should have something like this

```
    String newDisplay = display.Substring(0, CurrentPosition) + newChar +
 display.Substring(CurrentPosition, display.Length - CurrentPosition);
```

Comment: Hi mohammad jannesary,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am getting error : A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SelectionStart' property of type 'TextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

Comment: Hi; do you have problem?

Comment: yes..in Xaml to SelectionStart property binding is not happening with CurrentPosition      (A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SelectionStart' property of type 'TextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject)

Comment: you right; because SelectionStart isn't a DependencyProperty please see : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175618/how-to-bind-selectionstart-property-of-text-box)

Comment: Glade I Could Help :)